# Changing FavIcon in Vaadin using pure Java alongside Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, icons, vaadin, favicon

I want to change the favicon of the website in Vaadin that is combined with Springboot. I have also opted to go the pure Java route within Vaadin (no html page).

I followed [this guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/v12/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-icons.html), which explains that the icon I wish to use should be added in the `src/main/webapp/icons` folder where it will be automatically picked up, resized, etc.

I tried that to no avail, after which I found this [thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/12163090) and subsequently [this one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content). The latter link especially explains that Spring-boot has its own directories and that the `webapp` folder should be avoided. I tried using the spring directories, but again to no avail.

My resources folder currently looks as such:

[image: Resources directory]

My MainView as such:

```
@Route
@PageTitle("My new title")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
```

And my `SpringBootApplication` class as such:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyVaadinApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyVaadinApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The icon still remains the default spring leaf:

[image: Browser title bar]

Where am I going wrong in trying to set the favicon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `icon.png` to `resources/META-INF/resources/icons/icon.png`

[image]

Then:

- If you are use progressive web app (`@PWA` annotation) it should already work
- If you are use simple vaadin application you should to implements `PageConfiguration` and add link to your favicon.

```
@Route("favicon")
public class FaviconTest extends Div implements PageConfigurator {
    @Override
    public void configurePage(InitialPageSettings settings) {
        HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("rel", "shortcut icon");
        attributes.put("type", "image/png");
        settings.addLink("icons/icon.png", attributes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing the PWA annotation